# Left button pressed in mouse move in wpf

Tags: wpf, mousemove

On mouse move of a grid, left button pressed is not caught, but right button pressed is caught. Any one know the reason?

```
private void grid1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    //Entered to the loop
                }
            }

 private void grid1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                //Not enter to the loop
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There could be any number of reasons, but as you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't really tell you for sure.  There is certainly nothing wrong with the following code, that works as expected in a new project:

```
private void grid1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        //Entered the loop
    }
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        //Entered the loop
    }
}
```

The most likely reasons why your code never entered your `if` statement are as follows:

1. You weren't moving the mouse when clicking the left mouse button.
2. You weren't over the `Grid`, when you clicked the left mouse button.
3. You are handling the left click in a tunnelling event (`Preview...` event) and setting `e.Handled` to `true`.

If these suggestions do not help, then please follow the advice in the linked help page and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to further help.

Comment: Thank you Sheridan, the advice you gave here helped me big time.